# Connect to my database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I want to connect my HTML page to my database but I”m not getting it not sure why. What’s wrong with the code?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sibd02");

$query = sprintf("SELECT*FROM fornecedor ",
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they just don't mix.

Comment: please develop with error checking on **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /code/LLnXUb on line 5
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /code/LLnXUb on line 5 "** http://codepad.viper-7.com/LLnXUb

Comment: @Dagon Shouldn't that be line 4?

Comment: nope, php doesn't notice it until l it it encounter the ; on line 5 as it basiclly ignores line breaks

Comment: @Dagon True that. Yet, the "real" error *starts* on line 4, of OP's code anyway ;-)

Comment: agreed :-) i did not write the php engine (lucky for all)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which would've signaled the error that Dagon has so graciously supplied for you.

Comment: @Dagon Here we are talking about the real issue and its origin, where no one has yet to address below lol

Comment: jake pointed it out, logan just corrected it.

Comment: @Dagon Not quite yet lol Almost 99%. Edit: There, it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of issues with your code. Here is my cleaned up version of your code which should work:

```
// Set the connection or die returning an error.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "sibd02") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

// Set the query.
$query = "SELECT * FROM fornecedor";

// Run the query.
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

// Print the result for initial testing.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

// Free the result set.
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close the connection.
mysqli_close($con);
```

So let’s look at your original code with notes below on each issue:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sibd02");

$query = sprintf("SELECT*FROM fornecedor ",
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

- First this line `$query = sprintf("SELECT*FROM fornecedor ",` is incorrect syntax in PHP. And the `sprintf` is not needed.
- Then your MySQL query would fail because it has it’s own syntax error: `SELECT*FROM fornecedor` That `SELECT*FROM` should have spaces like this `SELECT * FROM`.
- Then you are using `mysqli_connect` for the connection but then using `mysql_query` for the query. Those are two 100% different functions in different classes. Mixing them like this will never work.

Comment: Check this line Jake `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error($con));`

Answer (score 0):

Mixing **MySQL** and **MySQLi** won't work. You can simply do this:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sibd02");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM fornecedor";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

/* IF YOU WANT TO PRINT THE RESULTS, HERE IS AN EXAMPLE: */

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['column']." ".$row['column2']." ".$row['column3']; /* JUST REPLACE THE NECESSARY COLUMN NAME */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```